# C# Error handling a data type string doing math operation

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Here is my sample code

```
int sinNum;
string sin;

Console.Write("\nPlease enter a SIN Number: ");
sin = Console.ReadLine();

if (isInt && sin.Length == 9)
{
    int secondDigit = (sin / 10000000) % 10;
```

This `int seconddigit` is where I am get an error:

> Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely going to want to add something like

```
int parsedValue;
isInt = int.TryParse(sin, out parsedValue);
```

You will then be able to do

```
int secondDigit = (parsedValue/ 10000000) % 10;
```

The reason that is failing is because you can't do division on a string.  You need to do some sort of conversion to a numeric data type that implements the / operator.

Just as an added FYI the % (mod) operator doesn't return the second digit.  Instead it returns the remainder from doing a integer based division operation.